# How to disable synaptics driver

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptics

Is there any way to disable the synaptics driver and use any other driver. The synaptics device on my laptop which is really old acts weirdly with synaptics drivers, weird as in the taps do not register most of the time, instead of registering the click the pointer just moves a bit so every time i have to use the buttons. Same issue was with windows 10 and with windows 8 and not with windows 7. The touchpad only seems to work nicely with synaptics drivers when it is in windows 7.
To get around this problem i used to disable the drivers in windows 10 and later installed windows presicion drivers which worked fine but cannot find a way to disable/change the driver in ubuntu.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`? Or lower [the priority](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311104/349837)