# Touchpad not working on ASUS TUF F15 (2021 edition)

Tags: touchpad, asus, elantech

I am using Kubuntu 21.04 on my ASUS TUF F15 FX506HM_FX566HM. The touchpad isn't detected in Settings and neither in `xinput`. Output of `xinput`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output of `lspci`

```
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
0000:00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller #1 (rev 05)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 05)
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 05)
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 05)
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 05)
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 05)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Shared SRAM (rev 11)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 11)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Management Engine Interface (rev 11)
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43bf (rev 11)
0000:00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43b6 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SMBus Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SPI Controller (rev 11)
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
0000:01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228e (rev a1)
0000:2d:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
0000:2e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller #0 (rev 05)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 174a
```

I updated my kernel from 5.11 to 5.12.5 to fix wifi as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1344040/14148) and the wifi started working (doesn't work after reboot but only shut down) but touchpad does not. Updated the kernel to versions 5.13.1, 5.13.2 and 5.13.4, 5.13.6, 5.14-rc2, 5.14-rc3 but doesn't work yet.

To make Kubuntu use synaptic instead of libinput (as i read elsewhere), I installed `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and removed `libinput` but after rebooting, keyboard and mouse stopped working so I had to install libinput again. Keeping both installed but increasing the priority of synaptic (as i read [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311104)) doesn't help either.

Also tried modifying grub by adding `i8042.reset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/824659) but doesn't work.

I think my touchpad make is ELAN as I see some other Asus touchpad issues (on and off askubuntu) with Linux mentioning ELAN and the directory `/sys/bus/i2c/devices/` shows a file `i2c-ELAN1203:00`.
More info

```
$ cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-ELAN1203\:00/name
ELAN1203:00

$ cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-ELAN1203\:00/modalias
acpi:ELAN1203:PNP0C50:
```

Looking into the output of `dmesg`, I see following logs

```
[ 0.861200] genirq: Setting trigger mode 8 for irq 167 failed (intel_gpio_irq_type+0x0/0x130)
[ 0.862657] tigerlake-pinctrl INT34C6:00: pin 226 cannot be used as IRQ
[ 0.862658] genirq: Setting trigger mode 8 for irq 167 failed (intel_gpio_irq_type+0x0/0x130)
[ 0.862688] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ELAN1203:00: Could not register for ELAN1203:00 interrupt, irq = 167, ret = -1
[ 0.862712] i2c_hid_acpi: probe of i2c-ELAN1203:00 failed with error -1
[ 0.876848] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
```

Issue reported on other forums

- [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1937056)
- [Kernel](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213857)

I have other issues as well like Bluetooth not working and sleep mode consuming significant power to drain the battery in 6-8 hours but will do another issue for them.

Comment: Issue resolved with a patched kernel. The patch is here https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213579#c56.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is resolved by using a kernel patched [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213579#c56). Used it to patch kernel version 5.14-rc4 and touchpad worked.

The patch has landed in kernel version 5.14-rc6. Installed rc6 using [Mainline](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline) and touchpad works.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how to solve this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/2f658f7a3953f6d70bab90e117aff8d0ad44e200 You need a newer kernel to gain function to your GPIO controlled devices. I found this issue with a i5-1135g7 hp probook 450 G8 affects the multitouch mouse and ethernet port.