# Asus TUF gaming F15 Touch pad not working

Tags: touchpad, asus

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 on this laptop. I don't know the year of this laptop but it has i7 10th gen and GTX 1650 on it.

I don't remember if before doing this:

[Brightness fn key shortcut doesn't work on ASUS laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471847/brightness-fn-key-shortcut-doesnt-work-on-asus-laptop)

The touchpad was working, but I think I pressed Fn + F10 just to test, and seems like it disabled my touchpad forever.

If I go to the config the touchpad does not even appear:
[image]

This are the outputs of xinput list and lspci

[image]

I was looking at this post: [Touchpad not working on ASUS TUF F15 (2021 edition)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352620/touchpad-not-working-on-asus-tuf-f15-2021-edition) but my kernel is newer than the one suposed to fix the issue.
This is my kernel version
6.2.0-33-generic

Update:

The FN+f10 key works and it shows the icon of the touchpad in the screen but touchpad still not appearing.