# Issues with Libinput, but then again also issues with switching to Synaptic drivers

Tags: xorg, gui, synaptics, libinput

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 with i3wm.

I have a [script](https://paste.debian.net/1279189/) which sets some settings. But since I'm using `libinput`, some of those commands result in an error:

```
property 'Synaptics Scrolling Distance' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
property 'Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
property 'Synaptics Edge Scrolling' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
property 'Device Accel Profile' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
property 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
property 'Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

Might be me, but I couldn't really find equivalent commands for `libinput`, so I tried to switch to Synaptics instead. However, that doesn't seem to work either.

I've followed this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1311104 - And now that dir looks ok, but I'm still apparently using libinput:

```
─$  ls -lahF /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
total 36K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May  1 15:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4.0K Mar 23 01:15 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Aug 22  2022 10-amdgpu.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4K Apr  4 08:20 10-quirks.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Jul 11  2022 10-radeon.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  590 Apr  6  2020 29-synaptics-quirks.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.8K Apr  6  2020 30-synaptics.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4K Feb 11  2022 40-libinput.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.4K Apr  6  2022 70-wacom.conf


─$  grep -i "Using input driver"  ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log
[    28.575] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    28.584] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[    28.588] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[    28.598] (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen'
[    28.653] (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger'
[    28.708] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    28.712] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[    28.721] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint'
[    28.730] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ThinkPad Extra Buttons'
[    28.752] (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen eraser'
```

What am I doing wrong?